# Opening the correct tab panel when clicking on hash anchor link on the same page (without refreshing the page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As the title says, i want to open a tab panel on mobile from sidebar, clicking a anchor link should send the user to the correct panel and should be visible/open at the same time. Any help would be highly appreciated. May be a piece of js/jquery. TIA

On mobile or browser resizing, clicking on the red floating button will open the sidebar and clicking on the "latest stories" link should bring the user to "Latest" tab panel which should be visible.

[Tab panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJCrd.png)